# What does the description of $% mean?

Tags: perl

In Perl, if I run this code:

```
print $a
```

it prints nothing, telling me the value of `$a` (or any other variable that isn't special) is `undef`.

However, if I run this code:

```
print $%
```

I instead get this:

```
0
```

From perlvar in perldoc I see this description for `$%`:

> The current page number of the currently selected output channel.

I don't understand. What output channel? One like STDOUT, or something else?

Comment: You can google 'perl special variables' to find answers to things like this.

Comment: `perldoc -v '$%'` will work on the command line as well. The stuff related to formats should be avoided; it's a legacy feature that doesn't scale well (as its configuration through global variables will attest).

Comment: There are lots of special variables like this: `$~`, `$|`, `$?`, `$$`, the list goes on. See [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Comment: For what it's worth, `$a` is, in fact, [a little bit special](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24a).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This relates to [Perls format/report feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) which allows you to write a screen format layout that somewhat looks like the end product, as opposed to say concatenating a bunch of strings in code. Useful for old terminal based apps.

[Perldoc says of `$%` in particular:](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

> The current page number of the currently selected output channel.

The rest of the page formatting variables will probably give you a hint as to what can be done.

`$%` - `$FORMAT_PAGE_NUMBER`

The current page number of the currently selected output channel.

`$=` - `$FORMAT_LINES_PER_PAGE`

The current page length (printable lines) of the currently selected output channel. Default is 60.

`$-` - `$FORMAT_LINES_LEFT`

The number of lines left on the page of the currently selected output channel.

`$~` - `$FORMAT_NAME`

The name of the current report format for the currently selected output channel. Default is the name of the filehandle.

Comment: OK, but what does that mean? (I'm still somewhat new to Perl.) What defines a "page", and what output channel? STDOUT?

Comment: it's part of the format (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) system; a very very old part of perl that isn't very useful to most people.

Comment: @ysth Thank you, I had no idea that even existed.

Answer (score 1):

[`$%`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%25) has something to do with [`format`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/format.html).

> The current page number of the currently selected output channel.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10657423)

Comment: @Rohit Gupta, What are you talking about?!

Comment: Come on, "something to do with format" is not an answer.  If your rep was lower, this would have been deleted by now.

Comment: @RohitGupta It's not a great answer, but the quoted part is, in fact, the answer. A link to [perlform](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) would have been better than "something to do with `format`".

Answer (score 1):

`$%` is related to the Perl formatting for creating reports. `$%` represents the page number for your report while printing the same.

You can find more details on how to use [Perl formatting](http://wwwacs.gantep.edu.tr/docs/perl-ebook/ch11.htm).

> By default, $% is initially set to zero and is incremented every time a new page begins. To change the pagination, change the value of $% before (or during) printing

An Output channel could be a file or a printer socket where you can write your formatted report.